Aws webrtc c sdk viewer/master disconnects after 10 mins of video streaming
So i am using aws webrtc c sdk for live streaming with both android and web sdk also,
the issue i am facing is the c sdk automatically disconnects after exactly 10 minutes, when connected as both master or viewer.
I am also sending messages over data channel plus also try to send message over signaling channel to stop it from idling out
STATUS respondWithConnected(PSampleStreamingSession pSampleStreamingSession)
{
    STATUS retStatus = STATUS_SUCCESS;
    SignalingMessage message;
    UINT32 buffLen = MAX_SIGNALING_MESSAGE_LEN;

    CHK_STATUS(serializeSessionDescriptionInit(&pSampleStreamingSession->answerSessionDescriptionInit, message.payload, &buffLen));

    message.version = SIGNALING_MESSAGE_CURRENT_VERSION;
    message.messageType = SIGNALING_MESSAGE_TYPE_UNKNOWN;
    STRNCPY(message.peerClientId, pSampleStreamingSession->peerId, MAX_SIGNALING_CLIENT_ID_LEN);
    message.payloadLen = (UINT32) STRLEN(message.payload);
    // SNPRINTF appends null terminator, so we do not manually add it
    SNPRINTF(message.correlationId, MAX_CORRELATION_ID_LEN, "%llu_%llu", GETTIME(), ATOMIC_INCREMENT(&pSampleStreamingSession->correlationIdPostFix));
    DLOGD("Responding With Answer With correlationId: %s", message.correlationId);
    CHK_STATUS(sendSignalingMessage(pSampleStreamingSession, &message));


CleanUp:

    CHK_LOG_ERR(retStatus);
    return retStatus;
}

I am not sure whether it's the correct way or not, but this doesn't happen when i start android as the master and web as the viewer, android also does nearly the same.
When android sdk is connected as master to both web and c sdk, only c sdk disconnects after 10 mins.
I went through the documentation provided by AWS that there is an idle signaling channel timeout for 10 minutes, i don't know a way how to prevent that, any suggestions would help
The expected behaviour is that aws c sdk also remains connected and streams video for atleast an hour.
